# Standard algorithm to operate on adjacent elements

Tags: c++, stl-algorithm, std-ranges

`std::adjacent_find` looks for the first two consecutive elements that satisfies the given predicate. I am looking for other algorithms that also has a predicate that takes the (previous, current) pair. This is useful for rendering polygons, computing numerical quadrature based on sample data etc.

In addition to `std::adjacent_find` there is `std::adjacent_difference`, which can be used to implement a one-dimensional filter, but is not useful if you only want the sum of op(previous, current).

Can such functions be emulated with some kind of view from std::ranges?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no special function for this, because you can just call the binary transform `std::transform(c.begin(), std::prev(c.end()), std::next(c.begin()), op)`. This works on the overlapping ranges `[c.begin(), c.end()-1]` and `[c.begin()+1, c.end()]`.

Similarly, other operations that take two input ranges can work on two overlapping ranges as long as they don't modify the inputs.

This can also work with greater differences than +/-1. It should be noted that this does not work on input iterators - they're one-pass.

Comment: @user877329: For readability, I'd wrap the `transform` call together with the binary `op` in its own function. This will be a short function, of course, so it's implementation is readable enough. And elsewhere, you use the function name, so the particular implementation doesn't matter.

Comment: @user877329 - for readability you wrap the one-line transform call in a little free function with _a proper name_, taking the distance and the transform lambda/function as parameters, and of course also your collections pair of iterators, you test it, then you use it however you want and forget how its done.

Answer (score 1):

Since C++23 there're `std::views::adjacent<N>` that reinterprets a given range in terms of a view of `N-tuple`s. Which is a powerful tool with *structured binding* allowing you traverse the range with named class fields. E.g. if N==2,

```
std::vector<T> v{...};
for (auto [former, latter]: v|adjacent<2>){...}
```

And obviously the corresponding `std::views::adjacent_transform<N>` view is provided as well, which will return view of results of applying the given N-nary function to every N-tuple:

```
for (auto i: v|adjacent_transform<3>(
[](T a, T b, T c) { return /*...*/; })) {...}
```